# Checking MetroCard balance outside?

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city

Is it possible to check my MetroCard balance outside of the subway in New York? For example, if I'm far away from a subway station while waiting for a bus.

Comment: You have tagged a city, but your question does not specify it. Please edit your question to make it useful for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time the only way to [check your MetroCard balance](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/easyuse.htm) is by using a machine in a subway station.

This is because while MetroCard does have a central database of all transactions, [it is not accessible in real time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetroCard_%28New_York_City%29#Technology), and the balance (or unlimited ride expiration) is encoded directly on the card's magnetic stripe each time you swipe it at a turnstile or farebox.

(This is what's happening when the turnstile tells you to swipe it again *at this turnstile*; in this situation something went wrong with the re-encoding of the magnetic stripe, and it needs to do it again.)

While in theory a web site could query your balance from the database, the information would be out of date and possibly useless.

Comment: Ahh, so that's what that message is all about. I feel like I just learned a secret.

Comment: You did. :) And make sure that you do swipe it again; in this circumstance the fact of your fare deduction has already been sent off to the database, so using the card at another turnstile will cause you to be double charged.